# Turf.js dissolve features not adding to Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, dissolve, turf

Trying to dissolve features with boundaries that touch with Turf.js. They all have a common attribute that is specific in the Turf option example. Console loge `console.log(regionsDissolved)` results in `'FeatureCollection', features: Array(0)}`. Which I think is expected. The results however don't add to my Leaflet map.

```
// add UC Berkeley regions to map with jQuery

$.getJSON('data/regions-ucb.json', function (data) {
    // refresher question - is this 'data' call an anonymous function passing to an anonymous function above?
    var ucbRegions = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);

    // create feature collection from ucbRegions
    var features = turf.featureCollection(turf.polygon(ucbRegions.toGeoJSON()), { combine: 'yes' });
    console.log(features)

    // dissolve features
    var regionsDissolved = turf.dissolve(features, { propertyName: 'combine' })
    console.log(regionsDissolved)

    // display dissolved features with red line and add to map
    L.geoJson(regionsDissolved, {

        // style layers so the buffer is visible
        style: function (feature, layer) {
            return {
                color: "green",
                weight: 3
            };
        }
    }).addTo(map);
})
```

Comment: Any possibility to share `regions-ucb.json`?

Comment: sure - https://github.com/zac-stanley/675-assignment-03/blob/main/data/regions-ucb.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `turf.featureCollection` statement

```
var features = turf.featureCollection(turf.polygon(ucbRegions.toGeoJSON()), { combine: 'yes' });
```

has wrong input. `turf.polygon` method expects polygon coordinates, but you are giving it feature collection `ucbRegions.toGeoJSON()` as input. Besides that, it's also unnecessary, since `data` already contains your feature collection.

Since you are dissolving all polygons, also dissolve selector `{propertyName: 'combine'}` is unnecessary.

Code could then look something like this:

```
$.getJSON('data/regions-ucb.json', function (data) {
  var ucbRegions = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
  var regionsDissolved = turf.dissolve(data);
  L.geoJson(regionsDissolved, {
    style: function (feature, layer) {
      return {
        color: "green",
        weight: 3
      };
    }
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

This gives the following result, which shows that not all the regions boundaries are overlapping:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was thrown b/c the turf documentation suggests it needs a featureCollection input: http://turfjs.org/docs/#dissolve. I guess this requires the fc b/c it's outside of a function.